# Multiple selection of classes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

This is my JS

```
$('.normal-box').click(function(){
    //unique row id
   var id = $(this).data('row-id');
   //its index according to the content array
   var index = $(this).data('index');
   //which card does this row belong to
   var card_name = $(this).data('id');
   var card;
   console.log(id) //el id de noten es de por si "link last_updated" concatenado
   switch(card_name){
       case "noten" : card = Unidos.CardManager.getCard(card_name); break;
       case "nachricht" : card = Unidos.CardManager.getCard(card_name); break;
       default : return false;
   }
   card.resetPriorityWhenClickedOn(id);
});
```

My HTML

```
 <script id="nachricht_card_row_template" type="text/html">
            <div class="normal-box" data-row-id="{{id}}">
                        <div class="img-box">
                            {{#if channel.image}}
                            <img src="{{channel.image}}" vspace="3">
                            {{/if}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="subtitle-box" id="nachrichten-subtitle-box">
                            <span class="options-title" id="title-text">{{channel.name}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="side-text-box">
                            <span class="side-text">{{formatDate datetime}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-text">
                            <div class="normal-text"><span class="text-formating">{{text}}</span></div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </script>
```

My CSS

```
.normal-box{ /*Container of other tiny boxes*/
    height: 70px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-bottom-color: gainsboro;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.3s;
}
.normal-box.show{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

As you can see, I want to select the `$('.normal-box)` , but I´ve got another function which adds a class which is .normal-box show... With the code above I can only make the .normal-box elements work, not the .normal-box show... This is what I mean with the .normal-box show clases: [image]

I have already tried this:

```
$('.normal-box, .normal-box show)
$('.normal-box, .show)
$('.normal-box.normal-box show)
$('.normal-box.show)
```

None of them work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: All your 'already tried' code examples are missing closing quotes

Comment: No, im using the console.log(id) in order to detect how is it working. It does not work with the normal-box show elements, but Im not getting errores

Comment: Those are from writing here, i tried them with closing quotes in th real code

Comment: @SebastianAmpueroMorisaki : Try this `$('div.normal-box').click`

Comment: @SebastianAmpueroMorisaki: I expect Ismail would appreciate it if you accepted his answer, since his answer fixed your problem. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, `$('.normal-box')` will match any element which has a class `normal-box` unless the elements are added dynamically then you need to use event-delegation like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.normal-box', function(){
   //Your code here
});
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: You are welcome. If this solves the problem, please mark it as accepted (so people facing the same problem in the future will be able to spot it easily).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.normal-box.show');
```

Comment: Still not working and normal-box elements do not work anymore

Comment: This will not solve the problem because this `$('.normal-box')` still match this `<div class="normal-box show some-class anything"></div>` !!!!

Comment: @SebastianAmpueroMorisaki are the DIVs added dynamically ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH yes they are

Comment: @SebastianAmpueroMorisaki please check out my answer !

Comment: @SebastianAmpueroMorisaki Try this $('div.normal-box').click